# Javascript make page only redirectable from another page

Tags: javascript, html

I have two html pages called `index.html` and `panel.html`. At `index.html` there is a login panel. Now I want that `panel.html` is only callable from `index.html`.
Is that possible? Everybody can just edit the url to `panel.html`.

Anyone an idea?

Kind regards

Comment: Don't do this in javascript, you need to use php with session.

Comment: Do you have any code samples or websites that explain that?

Comment: There is a lot tutorials on the internet, just google: simple login form with php

Comment: we can do this with url parameter in javascript, but not advisable to do so